# Mysql select not working for variable

Tags: php, mysql, select

Hello everyone I have interesting problem which I never faced before

I made a simple mysql select like this

```
$menuDig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gl98t_posichool_tricks WHERE `category_id` = '$cid'");
```

and when `$cid` is

```
$cid = $trick['category_id'];
```

which is `string(1) "1"` it works but when i type cid manualy like this

```
$cid = '1';
```

it does not work. I var_dump in both examples and the output is same `string(1) "1"`

Does anyone know where could be the problem?

Also the output is strange too cause `$trick['category_id'];` is integer in database but when i put it in `$cid` it is string

I firstly though i have to put integer too into `$cid` but it dont work either.

Comment: You don't need to use quotes for integer

Comment: your query is working perfect there was no any error if u put full code then i can better understand of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$cid = intval($trick['category_id']);
$cid = intval(1);
```

then in your sql do:

```
$menuDig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gl98t_posichool_tricks WHERE `category_id` = ".$cid);
```

Comment: thx a lot i feel like a dumbas now i turned on error display and i have seen that my connect fails in some cases i reapired connect and it works now fine thx a lot for your answers anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gl98t_posichool_tricks WHERE `category_id` = '$cid'");
```

Remove the single quotes from **$cid** and check again

Comment: The query will become like this after the quotes are removed: mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gl98t_posichool_tricks WHERE `category_id` = $cid");

Comment: You have to pass the 1 like an integer and not as a string if your data type fot cid in your DB is of int type

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$menuDig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gl98t_posichool_tricks 
                        WHERE `category_id` = ".intval($cid) );
```

and in your variable use this

```
  $cid = 1;  //without quotes.
```

Comment: thx a lot i feel like a dumbas now i turned on error display and i have seen that my connect fails in some cases i reapired connect and it works now fine thx a lot for your answers anyway

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the query without a variable and checking the result?

$menuDig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gl98t_posichool_tricks WHERE `category_id`=1");

Try this and check the outcome.

If none of the options above work, maybe there's a problem elsewhere...